# New Drive Api Connecting and Authorizing not working on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-drive-android-api

I follow these steps to login Drive in my application (Google Drive Android API):
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

I generated SHA1 fingerprint using debug.keystore. When I run application on my device, first connection fails, but hasResolution is true, and account selection dialog appear. The problem is that onActivityResult method is called immediately, before i select an account, and the resultCode is, of course, not OK.

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //some other code...

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DRIVE: connected");
    CONNECTED = true;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DRIVE: disconnected");
    CONNECTED = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DRIVE: connection failed");
    CONNECTED = false;

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            //mGoogleApiClient.connect(); whit or whitout is the same...
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data){
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                newNotification("Upload Fallito", "...", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: If this is something happening right now, Google Drive / Hangouts / Talk has been down for like the last 2 hours (at least here in NYC), which would explain why it is immediately failing

Comment: From far away, nothing looks wrong with the code. I don't understand why your 'onActivityResult method is called immediately'. It should return from account picker after user hits OK with the selected email in 'AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME' (going through onStop(),onStart() when leaving/returning).

Comment: Try moving your `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` from onStart() to onResume().

Answer (score 0):

For lack of time to analyze what's wrong here, I offer you to grab [code I use for testing here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA/blob/master/awaits/MainActivity.java) and give it a shot. Not pretty, but compact and functional. The authorization maze is touched in it's README. But I don't know your environment, so it may not be useful.

Comment: I try a piece of your code... i insert AccountPicker and startActivityForResult in OnConnectionFailed, but the result is the same. OnActivityResult called immediately

Comment: Why don't you try this: 1/ cut and save your launch activity code    2/ paste full MainActivity class there (everything from the example I mentioned), just preserve your 'package' name.   3/ rename the MainActivity class to whatever your launch activity was called before  4/ if you don't want your Drive to be touched, comment out the 'new DoStuffAsync(this).execute();' in onConnected(). It is difficult for me to analyze a little chunk of your code if I don't see the circumstnces. Besides, your problem does not look related to the Drive API, looks like logic flow problem.

Comment: I have not imported into the project com.google.api, because I thought it could handle the connection to Google Drive only with the classes provided in the package Play Services. The connection worked previously with the old API, the problem I'm experiencing concerns the new procedures.